# mvc3 not accepting proper URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've got a controller named "TafelController.cs" and a view named "Berekenen.cshtml". (the names aren't made up by me.)

the url "http://localhost:5181/tafel/berekenen" somehow doesn't work, even when adding extensions to berekenen like ".cshtml".
Decapitalizing the names of the controller and the view also doesn't work.
The thing is, I get the proper view when I make the Index() method the following.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View("berekenen");
}
```

which is weird, because that's what

```
http://localhost:portnum/tafel/berekenen
```

is.
when setting that page as the startpage the URL differs a bit.
Then it becomes

```
http://localhost:5181/Views/tafel/berekenen.cshtml
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be happening?

Comment: Your controller needs a method  `public ActionResult Berekenen() { return View(); }`

Comment: That solved it. Thank you. Now the problem is, how do you flag a comment as an awnser

Comment: I'll add one shortly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http://localhost:portnum/tafel/berekenen` is trying to navigate to a method named `Berekenen` on `TafelController`. You need to add the following method

```
public ActionResult Berekenen()
{
    return View();
}
```